# No such file or directory when saving record using CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, file, assets, cloudkit

I am trying to save a record to CloudKit. The record contains 2 strings, and one `CKAsset` that holds a `UIImage`. Here is my code for creating the asset:

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let filePath = "file://\(path)/NewPicture.jpg"

do {
    try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newPicture!, 1)!.write(to: URL(string: filePath)!)
} catch {
    print("Error saving image to URL")
    print(error)
    self.errorAlert(message: "An error occurred uploading the image. Please try again later.")
}

let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: URL(string: filePath)!)
record.setObject(asset, forKey: "picture")
```

When I was not using a `CKAsset`, the record was uploaded fine. However, now I get the following error:

> open error: 2 (No such file or directory)

How can I get rid of this error and save my record correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating the file URL correctly.

And move the code to create and use the `CKAsset` to where it should be used.

You want:

```
let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("NewPicture.jpg")

do {
    try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newPicture!, 1)!.write(to: fileURL)
    let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: fileURL)
    record.setObject(asset, forKey: "picture")
} catch {
    print("Error saving image to URL")
    print(error)
    self.errorAlert(message: "An error occurred uploading the image. Please try again later.")
}
```

I also strongly urge you to avoid all of those `!` in your code. Those are crashes waiting to happen. Properly deal with optionals. All of that forced unwrapping is going to cause problems.